# Webapp2: Using routes.PathPrefixRoute with Extended Routes

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm building a simple RESTful API. When I use `routes.PathPrefixRoute` with Webapp2's extended routes, it throws a 500 error. Using regular extended routes without `PathPrefixRoute` works fine. Is there any way I can prefix the routes but still keep my named args?

```
import json
import webapp2

from webapp2_extras import routes


class GetAllTodos(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        """Returns a JSON formatted greeting"""

        # TODO: Should retrieve data from a datastore
        greeting = {'greeting': 'Hello there'}
        json.dumps(greeting, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write(json.dumps(greeting))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    routes.PathPrefixRoute('/todos/api/v0.1.0', [
        webapp2.Route(handler=GetAllTodos,
                      name='get-all-todos',
                      methods=['GET']),
    ]),
])
```

Here's the error from the server

```
ERROR    2014-10-22 23:56:14,980 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/Users/ben.grunfeld/Desktop/Work/code/gae-restful-api/main.py", line 23, in <module>
    methods=['GET']),
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (4 given)
INFO     2014-10-22 23:56:14,984 module.py:666] default: "GET /todos/api/v0.1.0 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `webapp2.Route` handler definition is missing the route it's going to be handling.

Try

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    routes.PathPrefixRoute('/todos/api/v0.1.0', [
        webapp2.Route('all',
                      handler=GetAllTodos,
                      name='get-all-todos',
                      methods=['GET']),
    ]),
])
```

All I did was added the `'all'` part, now when you request `/todos/api/v0.1.0/all` your `GetAllTodos`'s `get` method should run.

Comment: [See more details here](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.Route)

Comment: Works beautifully. Bonus question - when I replace `all` with `<todo_id>` or `<todo_id:\d+>`, it 404's out. Prefixing with a `/` throws a 500 error. Any ideas?

Comment: @BenGrunfeld, make sure you define your handler as `def get(self, todo_id)` instead of `def get(self)` then.